# how can I play animation when before application start?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I want to add animation for loading screen. I used web service. When I get data, how can I add animation when waiting for getting data.(I use lottie pod )
Here is my code :

```
        animationViewLoading!.frame = self.view.bounds
        animationViewLoading!.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        animationViewLoading!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationViewLoading!.loopMode = .loop
        animationViewLoading!.animationSpeed = 1.0
        self.view.addSubview(animationViewLoading!)
        animationViewLoading!.play()
```

this code for getting data from web servis

```
func getDataformWebService(){

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://moodytest-env.eba-mmzgp9iv.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/categories")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Bearer \(APP_TOKEN)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    return
  }
    do{
        // splash screen creat  and property
       
        
        timersplash = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: ViewController.self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerfuncloading), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let categoriesDetails : CategoriesDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoriesDetails.self, from: data)
        category.append(contentsOf: categoriesDetails.categories)
   
        
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by before application start?

Comment: Before starting the first activity

Comment: I’m sorry, I still don’t understand

Comment: @AlexH I want the animation to run first when the phone boots. While the animation is running, I want the data to come from the web service.I want the animation to stop when the data coming from the web service is finished.

Answer (score 0):

What web service are you using? If you are asking about an api call one way to do it is by using dispatchGroup.

for example:

```
func getData(){

   let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

   dispatchGroup.enter()
   FetchData().fetchData(url: url) { (data, error) in
           print(data) //load or print data
           dispatchGroup.leave()
   }


    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
         animationViewLoading.stop()   //Stop the animation after data has 
                                         finished printing or loading
    }

}
```

Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: A dispatch group is probably unnecessarily complicated; Why not just stop the animation in the closure?

Comment: I tried that  but i got error :  com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (20): "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."

Comment: You tried to stop the animation in the closure or you tried what I said and it gave error? If what I said didn't work then you can try doing a DispatchQueue.main.async{ ...}. Anything to do with UIView or UIKit you will have to do it in the main thread